# Improve script performance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script:

```
function test() {
  const parameters = [
    {

      url: 'https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?buy_token_address=0xccc8cb5229b0ac8069c51fd58367fd1e622afd97&direction=asc&order_by=buy_quantity&page_size=9&sell_metadata=%7B%22proto%22%3A%5B%22189%22%5D%2C%22quality%22%3A%5B%22Meteorite%22%5D%7D&sell_token_address=0xacb3c6a43d15b907e8433077b6d38ae40936fe2c&status=active',
      cell: 'Sheet1!A1',
    },
    { 
      url: 'https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?buy_token_address=0xccc8cb5229b0ac8069c51fd58367fd1e622afd97&direction=asc&order_by=buy_quantity&page_size=9&sell_metadata=%7B%22proto%22%3A%5B%22190%22%5D%2C%22quality%22%3A%5B%22Meteorite%22%5D%7D&sell_token_address=0xacb3c6a43d15b907e8433077b6d38ae40936fe2c&status=active',
      cell: 'Sheet1!A12',
    },
    ];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  parameters.forEach(spec => {
    const data = ImportJSON(spec.url);
    ss.getRange(spec.cell)
      .offset(0, 0, data.length, data[0].length)
      .setValues(data);
  });
}
```

**Url**: Every URL contains a basic structure link with only difference of an ID. For example:
https://puu.sh/IWYZO/fecd1e1c3b.png

**Cell**: Every cell is pasted +11 rows from the previous one. For example: Sheet1!A1, Sheet1!A!12, Sheet1!A23, Sheet1!A34 etc.

**Problem**: Right now the app is very slow and sometimes i get a timeout error because of 6 minutes limit, so I tried to split all calls into different script files but I was wondering if there is a better way in order to make this script performs faster and better.

Comment: ImportJSON is undefined

Comment: I use this script for ImportJSON: https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs

Comment: Post it.........

Comment: I am looking to improve my script not the importjson one i think it's irrelevant with what i want to achieve.

Comment: Your script doesn't really do that much.  All of the heavy lifting is done in  ImportJSON

Comment: Exact copy of [How to improve script performance](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/164245/269219).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't paste the importjson script because it's more than 20k characters. However I posted a github url for you to check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As noted by doubleunary's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72019573/12306687), most of the bottleneck is coming from the multiple API calls to immutable.com. Try to plug the endpoints into something like [Reqbin](https://reqbin.com/) and you'll see that each call takes about 1.3 seconds with some peaks of 2(!) seconds. That quickly adds up.

There's one thing that you can optimize in your code, though, which you may want to keep in mind in other situations like this.

Your code is running `setValues()` each time you call the API. This means that every iteration in the `forEach()` loop writes 11 rows to the sheet. It would be better to just build an array with all the rows and then use `setValues()` to write them all at once.

In your code it might look something like this:

```js
function test() {
  //you don't need the cell on each URL, just specify the starting point
  let startcell = "Sheet1!A1"
  const parameters = [
    {
      url: 'https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?buy_token_address=0xccc8cb5229b0ac8069c51fd58367fd1e622afd97&direction=asc&order_by=buy_quantity&page_size=9&sell_metadata=%7B%22proto%22%3A%5B%22189%22%5D%2C%22quality%22%3A%5B%22Meteorite%22%5D%7D&sell_token_address=0xacb3c6a43d15b907e8433077b6d38ae40936fe2c&status=active'
    },
      url: 'https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?buy_token_address=0xccc8cb5229b0ac8069c51fd58367fd1e622afd97&direction=asc&order_by=buy_quantity&page_size=9&sell_metadata=%7B%22proto%22%3A%5B%22190%22%5D%2C%22quality%22%3A%5B%22Meteorite%22%5D%7D&sell_token_address=0xacb3c6a43d15b907e8433077b6d38ae40936fe2c&status=active',
    ];

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let data = []
  parameters.forEach(spec => {  
    data.push(ImportJSON(spec.url));
  });

  data = data.flat()
  ss.getRange(startcell)
      .offset(0, 0, data.length, data[0].length)
      .setValues(data);
}
```

Note that this will only shave off a few seconds, which isn't much compared to the real issue with the overhead caused by the API. If you find a better way to retrieve the data from Immutable you probably wouldn't even need to do this, but it's still worth knowing for your future projects and it's in Google's [recommended practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).

Comment: Hey thank you for the detailed answer! The reason behind those 11 rows is because I am pulling 9 orders from each request, example: https://puu.sh/IX2MC/f26381fc94.png
So the script must paste the url with 11 empty rows between each url call.

Comment: I see. If there really is no other endpoint that can give you more results then you'll probably have to live with the delays from the API. Regarding the 11 rows, the script I shared will still output the exact same result as your script with the headers and everything so you may still want to use it to reduce the amount of writes to the sheet. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried your code using a different url: `https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?buy_token_address=0xccc8cb5229b0ac8069c51fd58367fd1e622afd97&direction=asc&order_by=buy_quantity&page_size=9&sell_metadata=%7B%22proto%22%3A%5B%22377%22%5D%2C%22quality%22%3A%5B%22Meteorite%22%5D%7D&sell_token_address=0xacb3c6a43d15b907e8433077b6d38ae40936fe2c&status=active` and I  get an error: `Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 3 but the range has 24.`

Comment: That's strange. Did you change anything else? I just tested it and it works even combining it with the other ones.

Comment: I just replaced the links and sheet name. It works with the other urls but not with the ones i mentioned in my previous reply. This is the buggy script: https://justpaste.it/6s8zo please try it and let me know.

Comment: It pastes a few calls without problem but then it stops and shows the error, however this issue doesn't happen when i use urls like this: `https://api.x.immutable.com/v1/orders?buy_token_address=0xccc8cb5229b0ac8069c51fd58367fd1e622afd97&direction=asc&order_by=buy_quantity&page_size=9&sell_metadata=%7B%22proto%22%3A%5B%22189%22%5D%2C%22quality%22%3A%5B%22Meteorite%22%5D%7D&sell_token_address=0xacb3c6a43d15b907e8433077b6d38ae40936fe2c&status=active`

Comment: After further debugging i found out that the error caused by some bad url requests. So everything's okay with the script.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said at [Evaluate ImportJSON() custom function less often](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/164227/269219), the root cause of the issue is that you have *many* separate URLs that you want to fetch.

The optimal solution would be to find an URL endpoint that would you get *all*  the data with one fetch. You may want to study the API you are using in more detail to find whether they have an endpoint that lets you submit multiple IDs in one call.

Also see Immutable's recommended [best practices](https://docs.x.immutable.com/docs/api-rate-limiting).

Comment: Yeah that would be the best case scenario, however I couldn't manage to find an endpoint to get everything at once. Thanks for your reply though!